# What event is used when user ends Application with Swipe motion in 4.2?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I was wondering how we can manage the event where the user goes at the Running Apps list and swipes the application away. It does not seem to trigger go through `onDestroy()` and I haven't found any documentation about it.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering how we can manage the event where the user goes at the Running Apps list and swipes the application away.

There is no "event". Your process is terminated.

> It does not seem to trigger go through onDestroy() and I haven't found any documentation about it.

No lifecycle methods are necessarily called when a process is terminated, and none appear to be called when the user gets rid of your process by swiping it from the recent tasks list.

Comment: So how do I manage my application. Say for example I need to empty the database when the main activity is destroyed and I want to include all the ways that can be done.

Comment: @Peter: There are plenty of ways that your process will be terminated without `onDestroy()` being called on all activities. Hence, you will need to eliminate this requirement, or modify it (e.g., clear on startup, not on finish).